# Can this switching schematic be simplified with digital control?

Tags: jfet, analog-switch

This is a portion of the schematic of an old (80s) audio synthesizer/effect (Roland Juno 6). The two inputs are triangle waves (opposite phase). The circuit shorted by TR8 and TR17 is not shown for simplicity.

I need to replace SW4 with an electronic switch, so that I can control it with a microcontroller (3.3 V output).
Simply replacing SW4 with a DGxxx analog switch would be trivial, but I'm starting to think that it may be overkilll, and I'm wondering if many of the components highlighted would be redundant once I have a digital control signal.

Can anyone help me understand what this part of the circuit does, besides driving the two JFET TR8 and TR17?

[image: schematic]

Comment: Looks like it smooths out the turning on and off. Turning SW4 on (grounding the node) will discharge C39 faster than it charges when SW4 is off. C51 charges and discharges almost symmetrically.

Comment: *I'm wondering if many of the components highlighted would be redundant once I have a digital control signal* <-- I see no reason to believe that.

Comment: As well as slowly switching the JFETs (presumably to prevent a click sound) it's doing something with the two BBD drivers with asymmetric switching. Not so easy to replace all that unless you  gain a deep understanding of the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it smooths out the turning on and off so it's more of a gradual transition - two different ways. Because of D10, C39 (left of switch) discharges much faster when the switch is connected to ground, than it charges when it isn't. C51 (right of switch) charges and discharges more-or-less symmetrically (10k is not much compared to 150k).

To make the switch digital, you can leave all this R/C networks alone - there is no need to simplify anything unless it's broken or you don't like the smoothing effect - and just use an opto-transistor to simulate the switch. You don't even have to remove the switch; you can leave it in parallel.

Previously I showed an NPN transistor, but the ground level is different for the microcontroller and the synth, so an opto-isolator can be used just as easily.

The additional circuitry is very simple here. The transistor part of the opto-isolator goes in parallel with the switch. The LED part goes to the microcontroller, just like it does when you make it blink an LED. The resistor should be calculated based on the specifications for the opto-isolator.

(note: there was no built-in opto-isolator symbol so I drew one with wires)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvxMDo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you did want to rip out all the resistors and capacitors, you could feed some custom analog waveforms to some points in the circuit. Where, exactly, would depend on how much circuitry you wanted to replace. You could remove the circuit up to the two capacitors to insert your own on/off transition curve (or hold the voltage in the middle of the curve, or make it an LFO); or you could go deeper and control the JFET current (including separately on each JFET) or the voltages in the middle of TR11/TR12 and TR22/TR23. If the goal is simply to replace the on/off switch then I would leave all that alone.

Comment: thank you! I'd like to make sure of one thing: the existing switch is connected to -15V. The NPN you proposed have the emitter connected to ground. Would that work the same with -15V instead of ground?

Comment: @DimitriPetrucci ah, no, it would not, as it would bring the node to ground instead of -15V. If the -15V was your microcontroller's then it would Just Work. Otherwise, there are ways to make this work with more transistors, or you can just do it the brute-force way and use an opto-isolator instead :)

Comment: @DimitriPetrucci now it shows the opto-isolator circuit. Just as simple. I'm sure this is a common part in synthesizer design. If you are working on synthesizers I'm guessing you might have a pile of spare "vactrols" and they are very similar so you could also try one of those (though the resistance might be too high).

Comment: @user253751 In such case (to much resistance) the opto-isolator could be added to another transistor to form a darlington-pair.

Comment: @datenheim yeah, but you could also get a real opto-isolator. A vactrol is an opto-isolator but with the phototransistor replaced by a photoresistor. They are often used in synths as synths have lots of resistors and this allows you to modulate any resistor in the circuit to get a different sound.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, I related to such "real" opto isolator. Some of them have a low CTR which could be pimped if a second transistor is used in darlington setup. Of course it depends on part selection if that is useful or not.

Comment: @datenheim I think only a few mA are needed here. 30 volts over 10k ohms. Should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Analog switches are (MOS)FET based, it's a N and P channel in parallel operated with an inverter in between the gates.

You could replace "TR8" and "TR17" with a (DG303B), (ADG413), (DG403) SPDT's and remove the 560K resistor or TR29 itself.
Ofcourse you have to use transistors to level shift between 3v33 and 15 or 5 Volt to operate the Analog switches.

Transistor TR29 switches between a positive and negative voltage in an inverted way, operating either "TR8" or "TR17".

Comment: A lot of analogue switches use JFETs and not MOSFETs.

Comment: @Andyaka You could be right, works both ways (JFETS or MOSFETS) but in reverse: https://tinyurl.com/2mz2swcg (Falstad simulator simulation).

Comment: There are plenty of web evidence out there that tells you that it is not a pro simulator. Apart from anything else it looks a complete mess but, that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Andyaka it gives a good visual representation not using "real" component models and than doesn't matter, although you can adjust some components, like transistor, diodes, capacitors to real data. shows how current flows through wires, front or backwards. pretty nice if you're playing with NPN or PNP. the guy used the source of SPICE to build this.
Much faster than LTspice, for a elementary concept design it's good.

Comment: @Andyaka have you seen the other applications the guy has on it's website? pretty sure he is not a amateur, he is nice and answers your questions in contrary to Analog Devices that doesn't answer.

Comment: Sorry but it's not to be recommended for professionals or by professionals.

Comment: indeed it is a toy simulator, but it's often good enough to show concepts, but @NaturalDemon how did you not notice that your simulation has 100000000000000 amps flowing through it? You even put an ammeter to show the number of amps. This is something that's clearly outside of reality

Comment: @user253751 it normally can't, it will produce an error if your current is excessive, my original design was mosfet only, i only quickly pasted the FET circuit yesterday aside. don't have to use this simulation as i have analog switches in many flavors at home. It was just a test, will mail him. Used it to build many things and they all worked first time.